# How to create cartesian products between records for each group separately?

Tags: sql, sas

Suppose I sell services that span a time interval (days, months or even years). I have a Products table, where each product is listed, together with the `Customer_ID` and `Service_start` and `Service_end` date.

Now I want to list all combinations of pairs (`Service_start`,  `Service_end`) inside each customer; e.g. (table sorted by Customer_ID)

```
Lp  Service_start  Service_end  Customer_ID
--------------------------------------------
1     2-Feb-2014    8-Aug-2014   1
2     5-May-2014   20-Dec-2014   1
3     7-Jul-2014    9-Sep-2014   1
4    13-Jan-2014   13-Jan-2015   2
..      ...              ...     ...
```

I want to turn into

```
Lp  Service_start  Service_end  Customer_ID
--------------------------------------------
1     2-Feb-2014    8-Aug-2014   1
2     2-Feb-2014   20-Dec-2014   1
3     2-Feb-2014    9-Sep-2014   1
4     5-May-2014    8-Aug-2014   1
5     5-May-2014   20-Dec-2014   1
6     5-May-2014    9-Sep-2014   1
7    13-Jan-2014    8-Aug-2014   1
8    13-Jan-2014   20-Dec-2014   1
9    13-Jan-2014    9-Sep-2014   1
10   13-Jan-2014   13-Jan-2015   2
...     ...               ...   ...
```

The table is big enough that it doesn't fit into memory.

How it can be achievable by SQL? Or SAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SAS and SQL.  Here is the SQL idea:

```
select ss.service_start, se.service_end, ss.customer_id
from (select distinct customer_id, service_start from table) ss join
     (select distinct customer_id service_end from table) se
     on ss.customer_id = se.customer_id;
```

This is compatible with SAS `proc sql`.

In most dialects of SQL, you can add the `lp` column using `row_number() over (order by customer_id, service_start, service_end)`.  In SAS, you can use `monotonic()` or a data step after `proc sql`.